# Notification Icon Size VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

If I use the following code, then I get a nice large Blue Icon showing in the notification area.

```
NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(3000, "Title", "Message", ToolTipIcon.Info)
```

However, if I choose one of my own .ICO files, the icon is much smaller. I have tried feeding it icons of different sizes, 24, 36 and even 256px but they all appear to take on the same size.

Its as thought its defaulting to a small size somewhere but I cannot seem to figure out if this is true or not and if so how to show the same size icon as above.

Comment: How exactly do you choose your own icon to display on a balloon tip? As far as I can tell, it will only display one of the three icons specified by the `ToolTipIcon` enumeration. Are you talking about the tray icon itself, as opposed to the icon displayed in the balloon tip from that tray icon?

Comment: I am choosing a Icon from the Icon property of the Notification icon

Comment: Just to update on that, I have just noticed that Icon I choose is displayed in the tray icon. I must have misread the docs and thought that the Icon I chose was for the Balloon Tip. So from your reply, I assume these cannot be changed from the ones offered

Comment: That is correct, to the best of my understanding. There are two overloads of `ShowBalloonTip` and both use a `ToolTipIcon` enumeration value to determine what to display. Neither uses a property or parameter of type `icon`.

Comment: Thank You for the clarification that saves me time trawling Google

Comment: So are you still looking for an answer or is this question "close as 'caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced' ?"

Answer (score 0):

I am happy with the reply from JmCilhinney and as far as I concerned the question has now been answered